# How to avoid multiple instances of same app

Tags: android

Multiple instances of the app is being created when ever I click on the application icon .My AndroidManifest.xml is as follows .

```
<application
        android:name="com.kez.customgallery.UILApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
```

Comment: post all activity tags.

Answer (score 2):

Put android:launchMode="singleTop".

Comment: With single top fails on the fresh installation .that means when you install  for the first time it creates multiple instances for multiple clicks but when you remove it from the stack it behaving properly

Comment: refer this link  http://blog.akquinet.de/2011/02/25/android-activities-and-tasks-series-%E2%80%93-activity%C2%A0attributes/

Answer (score 0):

Change package Name in your AndroidManifest.xml file